# python sometimes recognized sometimes not recognized

Tags: python, cmd

I have made an executable from a python script using pyinstaller to check whether a system has python installed or not.

Here is the python code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('python -V 1> nul 2> zwzwzw.txt' , shell = True)
var1 = subprocess.call('find /i "not recognized" zwzwzw.txt', shell = True)
subprocess.call('del zwzwzw.txt' , shell = True)
if(var1 == 0):
    print ("python not found")
else:
    print ("python found")
```

What this code does is calls the python -V command and stores it into a text file zwzwzw.txt. Then it searches for the word "not recognized" in the text file. If "not recognized" is found then var1 = 0 and thus I get "python not found" else "python found".

The computer I am testing it on has

- python installed.
- on typing python in cmd prompt of the system, it recognizes python
- on typing python -V in cmd prompt of the system it shows the python version

In short everything is fine regarding python on that system. But on running this executable it shows "python not recognized as an internal or an external command". Usually this line is displayed when the path has not been added. But that can't be the case here as when i manually type python or python -v python is recognized. Its only when I try to call this command from the executable it shows this error.

However the command works fine on my laptop. It shows python found.

It seems the other system has the python path added to only the user variables and not the system variable. Is that why this difference is caused?
No I tried it after adding the path to the system variables yet it's not working.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using the full python path instead of just `python`?

Comment: That should not make any difference right? I am typing a command manually it shows a result and same command when the executable is typing it shows a different result. And the same executable recognizes python on one system and not another system.

Comment: Maybe you could print some useful diagnostic information, such as `import sys; print(sys.path)` and compare the differences between when the python is detected and when it's not?

Comment: thanks will try it out. :)

Comment: *I am typing a command manually it shows a result and same command when the executable is typing it shows a different result.* That why we use full paths when programming. You are allowing other things (like starting directory) to be determined by people other than you.

Comment: When I type manually the default starting directory is the same as that of subprocess's starting directory. So I don't think that's the error.